# How do i fade in/out a number of divs randomly every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with my code that i can't figure out. I want to show 4 divs that change every 5 seconds but somehow my function won't change every 5 seconds but every 1 second or so.

Html Code:

```
<div class="Image"><img src="image1.jpg">1</div>
<div class="Image"><img src="image2.jpg">2</div>
<div class="Image"><img src="image3.jpg">3</div>
<div class="Image"><img src="image4.jpg">4</div>
<div class="Image"><img src="image5.jpg">5</div>
<div class="Image"><img src="image6.jpg">6</div>
<div class="Image"><img src="image7.jpg">7</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
div.Image {
display: none;
}
```

Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var divs = getRandomDivs();

    fadeTheDivs(divs);
});

function getRandomDivs()
{
    return $("div.Image").get().sort(function(){ 
    return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5; //random so we get the right +/- combo
    }).slice(0,4);
}

function fadeTheDivs(divs)
{
setTimeout(function(){
  $(divs).fadeToggle("slow","", function(){
    var divs = getRandomDivs();

    fadeTheDivs(divs);

  });
}, 5000);
```

Can someone please help me?
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FyzXF/113/

Comment: You have your timeout set to 1000 miliseconds, which is 1 second. Is that the problem? Might want to use `setInterval( fn, 5000);` instead.

Comment: Hello Shilly, That is not the problem i forgot to change it to 5000 :P but when i set it to 500 it's still not fixed :) Thanks for your reply

Comment: Change to setInterval and remove the call to `fadeTheDivs` from the timeout function. Atm every 5 sec, two new timeouts are set instead of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using another tools like `promise()` and `delay()` no setTimeOut. Check this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var divs = getRandomDivs();
  fadeTheDivs(divs);
});

function getRandomDivs()
{
  return $("div.Image").get().sort(function(){ 
    return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;
  }).slice(0,4);
}

function fadeTheDivs(divs)
{
  $(divs).fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow').promise().done(function(){
    var divs = getRandomDivs();
   fadeTheDivs(divs);
  })
}
```

```css
div.Image {
  display: none;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:tomato;
  margin:2px;
  color:white;
  line-height:50px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Image">1</div>
<div class="Image">2</div>
<div class="Image">3</div>
<div class="Image">4</div>
<div class="Image">5</div>
<div class="Image">6</div>
<div class="Image">7</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your setTimeout delay to 5000 instead of 1000.
The set time out also needs to be moved outside of the div array because it is being called for each element in the div array. Thus creating a constant stream of 5 second intervals and creating the 1 second effect.

Here is a working version of the code:

```
    function fadeTheDivs(divs)
{

  setTimeout(function(){
    var divs = getRandomDivs();
    fadeTheDivs(divs);
  }, 5000);

  $(divs).fadeToggle("slow","", function(){

  });

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FyzXF/126/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That was not the problem i forgot to change it. I changed it now and it still trips when it loads the second time: http://jsfiddle.net/FyzXF/113/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FyzXF/125/
Here is a modified js fiddle. I'm not sure if this is the result you are looking for. The fadeTheDivs function is firing every second because you are calling it once for each item in the array. So it makes a constant stream of 5 second delays re-firing.

Comment: Thank you again for your reply. That's how far i got to but now it keeps showing the same divs after the first fadeIn

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FyzXF/126/
I forgot to move the randomization function to the set time out call. This should fix it up so it returns a different set each time.

Comment: still not working correctly. after the first fadeIn the second one comes in with 2 instead of 4. i kept seeing this problem as well ;\